# use qtcreator with gnu g++4.8 in mac os x

Tags: macos, gcc, qt-creator

I would like to set g++4.8 as the c++ compiler with qt creator.

I am in a OSX 10.8, QtCreator 2.8.0, and I have installed g++4.8 via homebrew.

I have setted the g++4.8 as the compiler: if I go in Projects > Manage Kits I have the GCC kit as default, and manually inserted a compiler called GCC 4.8, with compiler path `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/bin/g++-4.8`.

You can see it in the screenshots below. I also have `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/bin` in the Build Enviroment > PATH.

But, if I add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = --version` (I know it is dumb and it doesn't compile but it is just for testing) I receive in the "compiler window"

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1
```

(that is the same output i receive if I launch `g++` from the shell) and not

```
g++-4.8 (GCC) 4.8.1
```

(that is what i receive if I launch `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/bin/g++-4.8` from the shell) (and it is what I want too)

I remember that I had this problem in the past, I tried to resolved it hardlinking the g++4.8 to /usr/bin/g++ but it was not resolved (and just messed up everything).

What can I do?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and landed on your question...

Your question is how to make Qt Creator to use g++-4.8 for compilation.

The solution I devised is the following:

#### Solution

Add the following line somewhere in your project.pro file

> QMAKE_CXX = g++-4.8

for instance just above the HEADERS list

#### Rationale:

The makefile synthesized by qmake uses the variable CXX to determine the C++ compiler.
You can set the value of the variable CXX at the level of the project configuration file by manually editing it.

#### Pros:

It solves your problem, you will compile your project using g++-4.8 without having to change the g++ compiler for the rest of your environment.

#### Cons:

You have to manually set that for each project.

#### Question for Qt developers:

is there a more natural way to set the g++ compiler at the Kit level? If there is not way, that might be a useful functionality to add.