# how to set gcc as compiler in qt creator kit on macos

Tags: macos, gcc, clang, qt-creator

I installed Qt-5.15.0 (macos community binary), and started to use it for C++ development.
I have gcc-10.2.0 installed through brew, and available at /usr/local/bin/gcc,
which is a symbolic link to /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/bin/g++-10

By default, qtcreator uses apple's clang compiler, so I followed the answer [18847536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847536)
and set QMAKE_CXX = g++ in hello.pro file. But that gave me the following error:

```
"/usr/bin/g++" is used by qmake, but "/usr/bin/clang++" is configured in the kit.
Please update your kit (Desktop Qt 5.15.0 clang 64bit) or choose a mkspec for qmake
that matches your target environment better.
```

I see a couple of problems here - instead of /usr/local/bin/g++, the /usr/bin/g++
has been selected. And there is a conflict with the kit's compiler.

For the path problem, I followed the answer in [56759069](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759069), and changed hello.pro to
specify full path of g++, and to set the gcc's c++11 option like this in hello.pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXX = /usr/local/bin/g++
#CONFIG += c++11 console  # this was for clang
CONFIG += c++0x console  # this is for gcc
```

Now I get this error:

```
"/usr/local/bin/g++" is used by qmake, but "/usr/bin/clang++" is configured in the kit.
Please update your kit (Desktop Qt 5.15.0 clang 64bit) or choose a mkspec for qmake
that matches your target environment better.
```

So now, how do I tell the kit to use the same version of gcc, or to make a new kit that uses this gcc?

I tried visiting Tools > External > Configure > Kits, and adding a new kit there or to change the kit configurations. But I could not find a way to specify my gcc version there.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating a new Kit, you want to create new compiler entries. Look into Preferences => Kits => Compilers, and press "Add". Select GCC, and specify the path to it. Afterwards select g++ and do the same. Once you have done that, select the new compilers in your new Kit.

In theory just pressing "Re-detect" on the compilers page should also find g++ and gcc automatically.